# Django: Subclassing django.forms.widgets.Media

Tags: python, django, dynamic, django-templates, widget

I want to use a custom javascript widget in my Django 5.0 app. The javascript is not static, but dependant on template variables that I have already successfully attached to the widget as attributes (it's a MultiWidget in case that matters).

Since the [media property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/media/#media-as-a-dynamic-property) can only render static javascript, I was thinking of using the html template renderer in an own subclass `MediaDirect(widgets.Media)`. For that, I have also subclassed [`Media.render_js`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/widgets.py#L102) and [`Media.get_absolute_path`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/widgets.py#L128) so that it uses `django.template.loader.render_to_string` and pastes the content between a `<script></script>` tag:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import format_html

class MediaDirect(widgets.Media):
    """Media class that directly renders a template, using the media's parent as context.
    Important: Javascript or CSS *templates* are accessed per definition of
    settings.TEMPLATES, not settings.STATIC_URL, since they are not static.
    """

    def __init__(self, context, *args, **kwargs):
        self.context = context
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render_js(self):
        print("This is never called")
        result = []
        for path in self._js:
            js = render_to_string(self.absolute_path(path), self.context)  ########## <---
            result.append(format_html("<script>{}</script>", js))  ########## <---
        return result

    def absolute_path(self, path):
        if path.startswith(("http://", "https://", "/")):
            return path
        return path


class NoUISliderMinMaxWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):
    template_name = "widgets/nouislider_minmax.html"

    def _get_media(self):
        """
        Media for a multiwidget is the combination of all media of the
        subwidgets. Override method to use MediaDirect instead of Media
        """
        context = self.get_context(self.label, None, None)
        md = MediaDirect(context, js=["widgets/nouislider_minmax.js"]) ########## <---
        return md

    media = property(_get_media)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.value_min = kwargs.get("value_min", 0)
        self.value_max = kwargs.get("value_max", 100)
        self.value_step = kwargs.get("value_step", 1)
        self.value0 = kwargs.get("initial", [self.value_min, self.value_max])[0]
        self.value1 = kwargs.get("initial", [self.value_min, self.value_max])[1]
        super().__init__(kwargs.get("attrs", {}))

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        for n in ("value_min", "value_max", "value_step", "value0", "value1"):
            context["widget"][n] = getattr(self, n)
        return context

    def decompress(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, IntegerRange):
            return [value.low, value.high]
        if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)) and len(value) == 2:
            return value
        if value is None:
            return [None, None]
        raise ValueError("Invalid value: ", value)
```

This subclassed render_js method is never called however. Honestly I can't follow the process what Django does internally in order to render the Media instance. Somehow it passes [`widgets.media_property`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/widgets.py#L185), even though I've overridden the media property. Here I'm lost following the callstack comes from and where it goes.

Any ideas how to achieve dynamically rendered javascript are welcome.

Comment: So the `widget.Media.render_js` method is called by `Media.render`, which is called by [`Media.__str__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/widgets.py#L78). I would try dropping some breakpoints into those parent class methods and see if they're being called. Another thing to try might be altering your `NoUISliderMinMaxWidget._get_media` method, so it returns `str(md)`.

Comment: Well I spreaded some print-statements throughout the django codebase. Just elaborated the question a bit. Really, I can't follow, the structure is too complex for my understanding.